# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] - duplicate content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem and I do not know how to deal with it, the code is as follows:

```
<?php 
    if (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/catalog/')) {

        echo do_shortcode( '[shortcode1]' );
    } 
    elseif (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/catalog/site1/')){
        echo do_shortcode( '[shortcode2]' );
    }

    elseif (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/catalog/site2/')){
        echo do_shortcode( '[shortcode3]' );
    }
    else{
        the_content();
    }
?>
```

And now I want to display a different shortcode on each of the subpages - but I can not do it because the first REQUEST_URI contains 'catalog' and each below also.

And now when I'm on '/ catalog / site1 /', the data is displayed:

[shortcode1] and [shortcode2]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: You could make `/catalog/` the last `elseif`.

Comment: Reverse the order of the if / elses so the most granular is at the top. That way it checks "Is this /catalog/site2 then X, otherwise is it /catalog/site1 then Y, otherwise /catalog/? Z"

Comment: Also, depends on the URL but using something similar to `basename(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))` maybe with `parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)`.

Comment: It will not work as the last other - - if I give a condition I do not check, eg '/catalog/site3/' will display [shortcode1]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of your if/else, but to avoid displaying a shortcode for a condition you do not check, you need to perform a tighter check on `'/catalog/'` to ensure there is nothing following it. You can do that with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with a regex that checks there are no word characters after the final `/`:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/catalog/site1/') !== false){
    echo do_shortcode( '[shortcode2]' );
}
elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/catalog/site2/') !== false){
    echo do_shortcode( '[shortcode3]' );
}
elseif (preg_match('#/catalog/[^\w]#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    echo do_shortcode( '[shortcode1]' );
} 
else{
    the_content();
}
```

Note that since you are not using the result of [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) you should use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) instead as it is faster,

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, but it does not work as it should.

When I enter:

/catalog/sitesite222/ - everything is fine,

Once I enter the "catalog" - the information the_content(); is included

Comment: @danko12 did you enter just `/catalog`?